# How can I download photos from an iOS device to my Windows 7 PC programmatically?

Tags: c#, iphone

Currently I am working on a project, which requires to have an ability to download photos from an iOS device to a Windows 7 PC. I have found some solutions (in C#) on the internet (e.g. using WPD API, libimobiledevice library) but none of them works with my iPhone. There is a Windows.Storage API seems fit my need but it is introduced since Windows 8. I would like to see if there is any library / command line tool I can use so I can download photos from an iOS device to a Windows 7 PC.

Thanks

Comment: there must be such tool in C/C++/ObjectiveC, try Pinvoke in C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to talk to iOS devices over USB, [libimobiledevice](http://github.com/libimobiledevice) is probably the way to go.

I provide a version of libimobiledevice which works on Windows and which has C# bindings. You should be able to use the [imobiledevice-net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/iMobileDevice-net/1.2.1-r212) NuGet package to achieve what you want.

The [project site on GitHub](https://github.com/libimobiledevice-win32/imobiledevice-net) has sample code on how you can use the libimobiledevice C#; let me know if that's what you're looking for.